# Spring boot tables in database not updated when entity field is modified

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When using Spring boot to create an API, I've created an entity `User` with some fields like `firstname`, `lastname`, ...

The first time I've launched the application, the table is created in the database with all the fields.
Then I update one field adding `@Column(nullable = false)` to it.
And then, when I run the application again the field is not updated with the new attribute I've added to it.

In my `application.properties` i use this param: `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` but it's not updating anything i don't know why

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, the only solution I found is to delete the database, then it will regenerate the table correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I did the same as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ensures that a column cannot have NULL value. If the column have null value then SQL query is not executing. You can delete the column first then create it again.

Comment: I'm not sure I clearly understood your answer ! Do you mean that if an entry in my database is null it won't change the column property otherwise I didn't undertant your question sorry.
But if it's the case it's not working either because i don't have a rown with a NULL value in this column

Comment: Yes check is there any row having null value for the column

Comment: I check but there is no row with a null value for this column, they all have a value different from null or different from empty